# Scaling NSAttributedString with Size Classes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, nsattributedstring

I'm using `NSAttributedString` to make a section of a `UILabel` bold, and I've been looking at how I might scale the font across different size classes.

The only way I can currently see to do this is to use the existing font size of the label when adding the attribute:

```
CGFloat fontSize = self.label.font.pointSize;
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Abc Abc"];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                   value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize]
                   range:NSMakeRange(0,3)];
self.label.attributedText = string;
```

**To clarify:** `label` is a `UILabel` with a regular system font, and the attributed string is used to make the first 3 letters bold.

This works reasonably well, but couples the creation of the attributed string with the label. Is there a way to scale the attributed string without knowing the font size up front?

Comment: i use attributed stirngs all the time and I never declare the font for the UILabel when making the label if I'm using an attributed string. I'm not sure I understand what you are doing since the label resizes itself to the attributed string as long as you aren't setting a font size or regular text to the string

Comment: I've added clarification below the example. The UILabel has a regular font, and I want to make part of it bold, which I don't think I can do in iOS without setting the whole font attribute.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah, so it's you either use the AttributedString attribute to set the text or you set the text just the regular way. I've never done this as an "half and half" operation, if you don't set anything for the label, but you just set the attributedText property then the label resizes as it should, i can show you with a debugger logged example that is HUGE and uses a ton of attributed string properties and then logs the UILabel font which matches the attributed string font if you would like to see it. Let me know.

Comment: If you have an example on GitHub or similar I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: yep, I'll post something, hold up, I want to get you an answer, but the problem is that there's not really an answer to what you are asking, I just think you need to rethink how you are doing this that's all, one sec.

Comment: here's a huge attributed string with a lot of stuff going on:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/352ab058fc43ad1a65b9

Comment: when I run NSLog on the fonttype for the label, it returns this: <UICTFont: 0x7ffa60cae610> font-family: "AvenirNext-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt ... but clearly, the font size is BIGGER than 12pt font, but the UILable responds in such a way that it resizes correctly to accomodate the other fonts and the entire label shows up

Comment: if you run NSLog on the entire AttributedString attached to the lable, you get this:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fc0ace15cdd91ba5039b .. and clearly you can see that the other fonts are showing up

Comment: Rearranging fonts, and/or resizing them shows that the font of the UILable will autoresize to the lowest size of font for the fonts that you use to make the AttributedString, so the resizing is taking place, but there's more going on in the background to make this happen than just the size of one font, and NO, i didn't set the value of the UILabel's font

Comment: Thanks for the example, although I'm not sure it's showing what you think it is, I put a 12pt font near to where your label renders and the 12pt section appears the same size for all device sizes I tried on. However, I did some toying around, and by setting "Autoshrink" in the UILabel in Interface Builder, I was able to get my label to scale down to fit.

Comment: and in fact, it is returning as the font for the attributed string the first font that you declare, so you have to manage that

Comment: perfect, so you got it to work by messing around with the shrinking, very good, not sure how much this helps you, but just interesting to see the inner workings of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with @Larcerax, I found that I could use the *Autoshrink* property on my `UILabel` in Interface Builder to ensure the font scales down appropriately, which gives the (somewhat dirty) solution of using an obscenely large maximum font size which can be scaled down:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Abc Abc"];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
               value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:200.0]
               range:NSMakeRange(0,3)];
self.label.attributedText = string;
```

This does require deciding upon a maximum size ahead of time, though.